# Form not registering photo Django 3.0

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to get a photo to upload and the form is not seeing the file and in the form.errors, it says 'this field is required'. I've tried using `picture = request.FILES['picture']` to no avail and have also tried `picture = form.FILES['picture']` as well as `picture = request.POST.FILES['picture']` and `picture = form.cleaned_data.get('picture')` What am I missing? Let me know if you need anymore information

template

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Create {{post_type.title}} Post</h1>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
class PicturePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PicturePost
        fields = ('description', 'privacy', 'picture', 'categories')
```

views.py

```
@login_required()
def picture_post(request):
    """
    Creates new picture post
    """
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PicturePostForm(request.POST)
        print("is post")
        if form.is_valid():
            print("is valid") # this never gets printed because of the 'this field is required' error
            author = request.user
            content = form.cleaned_data['description']
            category = form.cleaned_data['categories']
            picture = form.cleaned_data['picture']
            privacy = form.cleaned_data['privacy']

            p_post = PicturePost(author=author, description=content, categories=category, picture=picture,privacy=privacy )
            p_post.save()
            #redirect to last page
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            l = []
            for i in form.errors.keys():
                l.append(form.errors[i])
            return HttpResponse(l)
    else:
        post_type = 'picture'
        form = PicturePostForm()
        return render(request, 'create_post.html', {'form': form, 'post_type': post_type})
```

The corresponding model field

```
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=f'profiles/{User}_gallery', max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by replacing `form = PicturePostForm(request.POST)` with `form = PicturePostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to complete the code before, please following

**views**

```
@login_required()
def picture_post(request):
    """
    Creates new picture post
    """
    form = PicturePostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            # instance new object p_post (this best practice if using forms.ModelForm)
            # commit=False (to save data on ram/memory device without database/hardrive)
            p_post = form.save(commit=False)

            # assign author attribute from thr current user session
            p_post.author = request.user

            # commit=True to move/save data from memory to harddrive
            p_post.save() # p_post.save(commit=True)

            return redirect('home')
        else:
            l = []
            for i in form.errors.keys():
                l.append(form.errors[i])
            return HttpResponse(l)

    post_type = 'picture'
    return render(request, 'create_post.html', {'form': form, 'post_type': post_type})
```

Comment: Not recommended this code **content = form.cleaned_data['description']** initialize variable to assigning value, because this case used forms.ModelForm on forms.

Comment: Oh! okay, thanks for the information; I didn't even think about that.